# How to SET a variable to the path of parent directory on windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

Struggling with command line again, I have figure out that I can store the current working directory in a variable like so:

```
SET current=%cd%
```

How would I set parent though? `SET parent=%..%` does not work, as it echoes `%..%`

Basically, calling a batch script `C:\a\b\myscript.bat` with the following contents:

```
@echo off
set current=%cd%
echo %current%
```

prints `C:\a\b` and I should like to *set* a variable `parent` so that it would print `C:\a` without changing the current working directory to `..`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Move up a directory, remembering the current, set the parent, and then pop down a directory, back to where you started

```
@echo off
set current=%cd%
pushd ..
set parent=%cd%
popd

echo current %current%
echo parent %parent%
```

Comment: Perfect! I now remember seeing the pushd and popd somewhere but it totally slipped my mind. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8):

You could also do something like this:

```
set current=%CD%
set parent=%CD%\..
```

It doesn't give you the canonical name of the parent, but it should always be a valid path to the parent folder. It will also be somewhat faster than the solutions involving pushd and popd, but that won't be the primary consideration in a batch file.

**Edit:** Note that all of the solutions so far, including mine here, will have problems if the current folder is the root of a drive. There is no clean and easy way out of that one, since there really is no parent of a drive visible to user mode.

Comment: That's another way to look at it. As to your edit, both ways seem to have no problems with the 'current' being the root of a drive. C:\ cd .. won't take you one level higher but stays at C:\ without braking, and technically C:\ is the parent of C:\ so that's cool. Won't be using this from root anyway ;)

Comment: Its just a source of a discontinuity, or a loop that fails to halt, so I thought it worth mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
pushd targetFolder
set current=%cd%
popd
```

Pushd/popd maintain a stack of previously visited directories.