# Batch: Get the full path of the folder in the previous directory?

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am trying to get the path of a folder that is one level up in the hierarchy of a directory and set it to a variable.

Now I have:

```
set LOCALFOLDER=%project.root%\builds\%BUILDFOLDER%
```

where %project.root% is the full path of of project directory (in batch string?).

Let's just say `%project.root%` is `"C:\Hardware\project"`.

I would like to go one level back the `%project.root%` (i.e. `C:\Hardwre`) and store that path in a variable. Is there a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to SET a variable to the path of parent directory on windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975521/how-to-set-a-variable-to-the-path-of-parent-directory-on-windows). (I found the link looking at the second item in the list of `Related` topics to the immediate right of your question; the list would have appeared while you were typing your question, so you should have seen it too before posting.)

Comment: I can't do that because I am not working from the current directory. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Please edit your question and clarify what you're actually asking, then. My previous comment is based entirely on what you *actually posted* in your question. :-) Your question specifically says "one level up in the hierarchy of **my current directory**", which the linked question answers precisely.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: The easiest way would probably be `set PARENTFOLDER=%project.root%\..\\`, which would mean "one level up from %project.root%" regardless of where %project.root% is located.

Comment: Have you... tried that? I made a batch on my Desktop and used that code, didn't work.

Comment: It does work. :-) Try this (each command on own line): `set LOCALPATH=%USERPROFILE% set PARENTPATH=%LOCALPATH%\.. dir %LOCALPATH% dir %PARENTPATH%`. The reference to `PARENTPATH` is to the proper location; IOW, it points to the parent folder of `LOCALPATH`.

Comment: ken is right \..\ is like doing cd.. it means parent folder

Answer (score 4):

Path manipulation gets a little messy. One option is the following:

```
set "project.root=C:\Hardware\project"
set "X=%project.root%"
:l
if "%X:~-1%"=="\" goto al
set "X=%X:~0,-1%"
goto l
:al
set "X=%X:~0,-1%"
set "project.parent=%X%"
echo %project.parent%
```

which successively removes the last character until a `\` is removed.

If you're dealing with actual paths in your file system I'd say you use the `pushd` approach:

```
pushd %project.root%
cd ..
set project.parent=%CD%
popd
```

This temporarily sets your current directory, stores the path and returns.

Answer (score -1):

This is quite simple:

To get the current directory in a variable simply say
set /a VARIABLE=cd
To go back a level say:
cd ..

now if you say "set /a VARIABLE=cd" It is set to the previous directory

Comment: I thought that it would be %cd% ... :P as in: set var=%cd%

Comment: That's nonsense. `set /a` is for *arithmetic*. You'd just get `0` as a result.

Comment: @Joey but set var=%cd% does make var contain the Current Directory... :)

Comment: There wasn't any `%` in their answer.